# Looping through a pandas Dataframe to get values from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes. The first dataframe contains the location of different circles over time. Example: df1 =

```
               x      y      time
circle
 1.0          235    133     1.0
 2.0          236    133     1.0
 3.0          245    425     1.0
 4.0          215    325     2.0
 5.0          287    203     4.0
 6.0          394    394     5.0
```

The second dataframe is organised exactly like the first, but contains the locations of squares at different times. Example: df2 =

```
               x      y      time
square
 1.0          243    233     1.0
 1.0          293    436     2.0
 2.0          189    230     3.0
 2.0          189    233     4.0
 3.0          176    203     4.0
 3.0          374    394     5.0
```

I would like to figure out how to loop through the dataframe df1 to access all the present squares in df2 at each time point, to find out which is closest.

Example output:

```
               x      y      time      closest_sq      sq_x      sq_y
circle
 1.0          235    133     1.0          1.0           243       233
 2.0          236    133     1.0          1.0           243       233
 3.0          245    425     1.0          1.0           243       233
 4.0          215    325     2.0          1.0           243       233
 5.0          287    203     4.0          2.0           189       233    
 6.0          394    394     5.0          3.0           374       394
```

I'm guessing I have to use either iterrows() or itertuples() in a for loop to get at this but I'm not sure, and scipy cdist to get the distance.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Edited the question to show an example output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first make our two DataFrames, circles and squares.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
circles = pd.DataFrame({'circle': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 6.0},
         'time': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 4.0, 5: 5.0},
         'x': {0: 235, 1: 236, 2: 245, 3: 215, 4: 287, 5: 394},
         'y': {0: 133, 1: 133, 2: 425, 3: 325, 4: 203, 5: 394}})
circles
-------------------------------
        circle  time    x   y
    0   1.0     1.0    235  133
    1   2.0     1.0    236  133
    2   3.0     1.0    245  425
    3   4.0     2.0    215  325
    4   5.0     4.0    287  203
    5   6.0     5.0    394  394
```

---

```
squares = pd.DataFrame({'square': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 3.0},
                        'time': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 4.0, 5: 5.0},
                        'x': {0: 243, 1: 293, 2: 189, 3: 189, 4: 176, 5: 374},
                        'y': {0: 233, 1: 436, 2: 230, 3: 233, 4: 203, 5: 394}})\
                        .set_index('time')

squares
------------------
    square  x   y
time            
1.0  1.0    243 233
2.0  1.0    293 436
3.0  2.0    189 230
4.0  2.0    189 233
4.0  3.0    176 203
5.0  3.0    374 394
```

So those are our DataFrames, let's define a function that we can apply to each circle in circles which will return us the corresponding closest square.

```
def closest_square(circleseries):
"""
This function takes a pd.Series which is what pd.DataFrame.apply gives 
the function that you apply, in this case to the DataFrame circles. So 
the pd.Series it will get from apply will represent a single circle. 
We use loc to get the squares at the correct time point which gives us
a DataFrame that is a subset of squares. We then use assign to give
that DataFrame an extra column with the distance and the ID of the
circle. Finally we sort this whole thing in ascending order by the 
distance to our circle, take the square with the lowest distance to
our circle (iloc[0]). We also reset the index because we don't want
the time column from squares to be our but a regular column.
"""
return squares.loc[[circleseries.time], :]\
           .assign(distance = lambda s: np.sqrt( (s.x- circleseries.x)**2 + (s.y- circleseries.y)**2),
 circle=circleseries.circle)\
           .sort_values('distance', ascending=True)\
           .reset_index()\
           .iloc[0]
```

Let's apply the function to circles.

```
circles.apply(closest_square, axis=1)
--------------------------------------------------------
        time    square  x       y       circle  distance
   0    1.0     1.0    243.0    233.0   1.0    100.319490
   1    1.0     1.0    243.0    233.0   2.0    100.244701
   2    1.0     1.0    243.0    233.0   3.0    192.010416
   3    2.0     1.0    293.0    436.0   4.0    135.665029
   4    4.0     2.0    189.0    233.0   5.0    102.489024
   5    5.0     3.0    374.0    394.0   6.0    20.000000
```

Because we added the circle column in our apply, we can simply merge on it.

```
circles.merge(circles.apply(closest_square, axis=1), on='circle')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    circle  time_x  x_x y_x time_y  square  x_y     y_y     distance
0   1.0     1.0     235 133 1.0     1.0     243.0   233.0   100.319490
1   2.0     1.0     236 133 1.0     1.0     243.0   233.0   100.244701
2   3.0     1.0     245 425 1.0     1.0     243.0   233.0   192.010416
3   4.0     2.0     215 325 2.0     1.0     293.0   436.0   135.665029
4   5.0     4.0     287 203 4.0     2.0     189.0   233.0   102.489024
5   6.0     5.0     394 394 5.0     3.0     374.0   394.0   20.000000
```

Comment: works great for this dataset but when slightly modified, I get an error? ('None of [[6.0]] are in the [index]', 'occurred at index 5')

Comment: I used the following:

`squares = pd.DataFrame({'square': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 6.0, 6: 7.0, 7: 8.0},
                        'time': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 3.0, 6: 4.0, 7: 5.0 },
                        'x': {0: 243, 1: 293, 2: 189, 3: 189, 4: 176, 5: 374, 6: 111, 7: 239},
                        'y': {0: 233, 1: 436, 2: 230, 3: 233, 4: 203, 5: 394, 6: 171, 7: 284}}).set_index('time')`

Comment: and:
`circles = pd.DataFrame({'circle': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 6.0, 6: 7.0, 7: 8.0},
         'time': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 6.0, 6: 7.0, 7: 8.0},
         'x': {0: 235, 1: 236, 2: 245, 3: 215, 4: 287, 5: 394, 6: 132, 7: 104},
         'y': {0: 133, 1: 133, 2: 425, 3: 325, 4: 203, 5: 394, 6: 104, 7: 258}})`

Comment: Yes because you now have circles in circles at time points for which you have no squares. 
You can avoid this error by subfiltering the circles to only include the timepoints which you have squares for, like so:
```common_timepoints = np.intersect1d(squares.time.unique(), circles.time.unique())```
```filtered_circles = circles.set_index('time').loc[[common_time_points]].reset_index()```

Then you can just do what I did in my answer:
To get the closest square:
`filtered_circles.apply(closest_square, axis=1)`

Comment: To get the merged DataFrame:


`circles.merge(filtered_circles.apply(closest_square, axis=1), on='circle')`

The latter will have NaNs on the right side for all the circles at time points for which there is no square.

Comment: Also on the subject of speed - apply is a good amount faster than iterrows, see this [blogpost](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6). If speed and/or memory end up being a limiting factor for your question, you should look into [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) for speed and [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) for dealing with columnar datasets that are too large to fit into memory. Both are rather user-friendly but unnecessary if your problem isn't large scale.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 3):

You can user `pd.merge()` to join the dataframes and then use `df.loc`. Here's how you can do this with your dataframes:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='time',how='inner')
df4 = df3.loc[df3['time'] == 1.0]
df4[['circle','square','time']].head()
```

You can optimize the above code by using `inplace=True`.

Comment: Sorry, posted answer just before your edit man.! But see if the above code helps you.!

Comment: thank you, though its not exactly what I'm looking for